# CakePHP join multiple schemas

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

Currently I'm making application in CakePHP connection to SQL Server.

On my SQL database I have multiple schemas (instead of multiple databases - good practices). How can I for example join multiple schemas to get all data in one response?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this -
$books = $this->Books->find('all',['fields' => ['id' => 'Books.id', 'name' => 'Books.name''category_id' => 'bc.category_id','category' => 'ac.category']])
                ->join([
                    'bc' => [
                        'table' => 'Book_categories',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'bc.book_id = Books.id'
                    ],
                    'ac' => [
                        'table' => 'All_categories',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => 'bc.category_id = ac.id'
                    ]
                ]);
```

note that the field names are mentioned as associative array ('alias' => 'column ref'), you can mention only the column names but that will fetch the results of different tables in different arrays ( eg, [ac] array will contain [category] => 'cat_name' )